# Get selected item from a ListViewByQuery in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a webpart with a custom list, a ListViewByQuery, and now I need to get the selected row when a button is pressed. Somehow I have understood that I should use ECMAScript for this but I can't understand howto do this:

my Showlist.ascx file looks like this:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ListCasesUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Codan_LotMix.ListCases.ListCasesUserControl" %>
    <style type="text/css">

        .style1
        {
            font-size: large;
        }
        </style>
    <p class="style1">
        <strong>Ärenden</strong></p>
    <p>
       <SharePoint:ListViewByQuery ID="caseView" runat="server" />
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <asp:Button ID="GetCase" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="GetCase_Click" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Selected" runat="server" Width="557px"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the ShowList.cs has this (here the ListViewByQuery list is created);

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["cCase_Instance"];
        caseView.List = list;
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery(caseView.List.DefaultView);
        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='cCase_Customer'/><FieldRef Name='cCase_Date'/><FieldRef Name='cCase_CreatedBy'/>";
        query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='cCase_Date' Ascending='FALSE'></";
        caseView.Query = query;


    }

    protected void GetCase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Selected.Text = "HERE SHOULD THE SELECTED ROW BE VISIBLE";
    }
```

How do I use the ECMAScript to get the Selected row?  Or in what other way can I get the text from the row selected when I have pressed the button?

/M

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but I came across this post:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/19/programmatically-get-selected-documents-from-sharepoint-2010-document-library/

This one's more about list items than ListViewByQuery but may still be helpful
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/16/get-all-list-items-using-ecmascript-sharepoint-2010/

HTH.